# Prove that there will always be two elements $x_1, x_2\in A\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x_1-x_2| < p$ for all $p\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, integers

So, I've been trying this proof for a week now, and got no clues on how to find such $x_1$ and $x_2$. So, here's the full question:

> Let $A = \left\lbrace x\mid x = \displaystyle\frac{1}{n + 1}, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$  be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that, fixed any positive real number $p$, there will always be two elements of $A$ such that their distance on the real line is less than $p$.

I tried to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $A$ in a way I could logically find that $|x_1 - x_2|$ is indeed less than $p$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach.

Define the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ such that $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}.$  By definition, $\langle a_n\rangle = A.$
Further $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0.$

Since $p \in \Bbb{R^+}$, and since $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, there exists $N \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $a_N < p.$

Then, you have that $p > a_N > a_{(N+1)} > 0 \implies p > [a_N - a_{(N+1)}] = |a_n - a_{(N+1)}|.$

Answer (score 1):

I will call $x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$, so that A can be read as $\{x_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Now, notice that:
$$|x_n - x_{n-1}| = \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)},$$
which goes to 0 as $n$ goes to infinity. In particular, given $p>0$ there exists a natural number $n_p$ such that if $n\geq n_p$, then $||x_n-x_{n+1}| - 0| = |x_n-x_{n+1}| < p$. This concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s consider two consecutive elements of $A$. We want to prove that for any $p>0$, we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|\frac{1}{N+1}-\frac{1}{N+2}| < p$. This is very similar to the definition of a limit:
$$x_n \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow} 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \forall p>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n>N, |x_n|<p$$

Now notice that $\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\lim} |\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}|=0$, and apply the previous definition. Hope it helps you to solve your question!